# AGPL In Practice

Tags: agpl-3.0

Suppose I write a server-based application that I wish to release under the AGPL and expose publicly. What concrete steps do I need to take in order to satisfy [clause 13](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html#section13)? Is it enough to add a valid link to a public `git` repository on an "About" page? Does the link have to appear on every page of the application? Does it need to be a direct download, rather than a link to a `github` project or similar? Are there other things I need to be careful about the design of the server to prevent it from accidentally violating the license?

Comment: As extra reading in to follow Philppe's good answer, I'll point to my relevant answer on [Do I have to offer the source of an AGPL (v3.0) licensed Web app even if I didn’t modify it?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/650/50)

Answer (score 5):

> Suppose I write a server-based application that I wish to release under the AGPL and expose publicly. What concrete steps do I need to take in order to satisfy clause 13?

As the author of the application, I can incorporate any or NO mechanism that would trigger the requirements of the [AGPL section 13](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html#section13). So there are no specific steps I need to take. I am the author.

The point here is that the onus is on a user that would modify and redistribute or perform publicly my application. My application may not contain any such built-in mechanism to download the corresponding sources yet if a user modifies my code, then they would have to meet the requirements of section 13 nonetheless.

So I can include nothing or anything. If I include something I could include anything I like:

- a valid link to a public git repository on an "About" page
- the link may appear on every page of the application
- it can be a direct download
- it can be a link to a Github project or similar

Or I can include nothing at all. I am the author and I can do as I please.

If I include some or any of the above, a user:

- may not remove any of these,
- if they modify my code, they may need to update the mechanism (such as update the link, or the code that creates a tarball or else) such that this points to **the current code with their modifications** rather than to my original unmodified code.

See also this excellent related [answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/791/947) from [@apsillers](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/50/apsillers) who contacted the FSF on a similar topic (this is small excerpt):

> So, if you use an unmodified AGPL application that doesn't have download-source functionality, you are not required to add one or otherwise offer the source to users. If you do modify the software, of course, you are required to add a mechanism to allow users to download your modified source.