# AGPLv3 source redistribution: when does it apply to my code for a server-side Java app using an AGPL-licensed library?

Tags: licensing, agpl-3.0, source-code, redistribution

I have written a Java program designed to run server-side with a plain HTML web interface:

- My app is based based on Apache Tomcat and I wrote a bunch of servlets.
- I am reusing and I have integrated in this app one single third-party library that is licensed under the AGPLv3.
- This library performs some file transformation and report creation of sorts using data that I feed it with when I call its methods.
- This library is not part of code producing any of my web UI, though its output can be made available to users for download in my web app.
- I use this library as-is and **unmodified** fetched straight from Maven Central: I am merely calling its methods in my own code.
- This library **does not have a corresponding source code download mechanism builtin**  (e.g. there is no mechanism as defined in the AGPLv3 Section 13 or in the AGPLv3 "How To").

In each of the following cases, would I have to **redistribute the source code of my own application and of this library** per the AGPLv3?

1. When I run this application on a private company network and its is only available internally to my company employees?
2. When I run this application on a public web site on the open internet?
3. When I redistribute this application as a packaged software product to possible customers?
4. What if in my case 2. the author of the library insist that the copyleft is triggered even if I am using the library unmodified and that I must redistribute the whole source code, including my own? [note: this is an addition following answers and comments]

Comment: Note: If you wonder why I created this question and posted a self-answer: this to cut short on the comments thread in this answer: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/663/947 and provide a more comprehensive explanation of  my points

Comment: Note that your interpretation  creates a "Middleman Loophole" that turns the AGPL into LGPL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several Q&A about the AGPLv3 on this site and some answers are sending vague or mixed signals. 
Here is a (hopefully) clear and definitive answer with references.

First the AGPLv3 is essentially the same license as the GPLv3 with the addition of [Section 13](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section13) as you can see in this [side-by-side diff](https://gist.github.com/pombredanne/2a8d85da552dfab9b8173f771b6a4f98/revisions) of the two license texts:

> 13. Remote Network Interaction; Use with the GNU General Public License.
>
> Notwithstanding any other provision of this License, if you modify the Program, your modified version must prominently offer all users interacting with it remotely through a computer network (if your version supports such interaction) an opportunity to receive the Corresponding Source of your version by providing access to the Corresponding Source from a network server at no charge, through some standard or customary means of facilitating copying of software. [...]

The intent of this new section is spelled out clearly in the [preamble](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#preamble) (bold emphasis is mine):

> The GNU General Public License permits making a **modified version** and letting the public access it on a server without ever releasing its source code to the public.
>
> The GNU Affero General Public License is designed specifically to ensure that, in such cases, the **modified source code** becomes available to the community. It requires the operator of a network server to provide the source code of the **modified version** running there to the users of that server. Therefore, public use of a **modified version**, on a publicly accessible server, gives the public access to the source code of the **modified version**.

---

Now let's look at which parts of the AGPLv3 are triggered in your four cases:

### Modification

You are using an unmodified `exact copy` of this library. Therefore this definition of [Section 0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section0) is relevant. You are **not** using a `modified version` if you are using an `exact copy` (bold emphasis is mine):

> To "modify" a work means to copy from or adapt all or part of the work in a fashion requiring copyright permission, **other than the making of an exact copy**. The resulting work is called a "modified version" of the earlier work or a work "based on" the earlier work.

Therefore per [Section 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section2) in all three cases (bold emphasis is mine):

> This License explicitly affirms your unlimited permission to run the **unmodified** Program.

And therefore since you did not modify it, the [section 13](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section13) is not triggered.

### Propagation

- In case 1, you certainly do not "propagate" the work: you are instead `executing it on a computer`.
- In case 2 you may be "propagating" the work as you are somehow indirectly `making it available to the public` by running your public web server. Yet this is not 100% clear as you are not distributing a copy. I take a prudent point of view that you may be "propagating".
- In case 3 you are clearly "propagating" the work as you [re]`distribute` the code.

(as defined in [section 0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section0))

> To "propagate" a work means to do anything with it that, without permission, would make you directly or secondarily liable for infringement under applicable copyright law, except executing it on a computer or modifying a private copy. Propagation includes copying, distribution (with or without modification), making available to the public, and in some countries other activities as well.

### Conveying

You are clearly only conveying in case 3. In case 2, you are propagating but not conveying as there is `no transfer of a copy`.

(as defined in [section 0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section0)) (bold emphasis is mine)

> To "convey" a work means any kind of propagation that enables other parties to make or receive copies. **Mere interaction with a user through a computer network, with no transfer of a copy, is not conveying.**

Your further mention that as such this library does not have a built-in mechanism to offer a download of its corresponding source code as explained in the [Section 13](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section13). Since this library does not have a built-in mechanism to self-download its corresponding source code, your propagation does not `enables other parties to make or receive copies`. Which further reinforces the fact that you are not "conveying" in case 2.

You also mention that this library takes your data and create some report format. I will assume that therefore the output is not subject to the license of the library itself and this part of [Section 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section2) does **not apply** in your case:

> The output from running a covered work is covered by this License only if the output, given its content, constitutes a covered work.

Finally, in all cases your application is combined and depends on the AGPL-licensed library and I would consider that its copyleft extends to your own source code.

---

But when is the copyleft effectively triggered in these cases? (and of course the copyleft requirement to eventually redistribute the source code of your own application?)

Since you are using the library unmodified, the key is whether you are either propagating or conveying or both

> **1. when I run this application on a private company network and its is only available internally to my company?**

In this case, you are using the library internally unmodified, without neither conveying nor propagating:
And per [Section 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section2)

> This License explicitly affirms your unlimited permission to run the unmodified Program. [...]
>   You may make, run and propagate covered works that you do not convey, without conditions so long as your license otherwise remains in force.

This is all I have to say about your case 1: **you do not have to make any source code redistribution** of your own code using this library and of this library in this case.

> **2. when I run this application on a public web site on the open internet?**

You are using the library unmodified, and there is no built-in Section 13 corresponding source code download mechanism. In this case you are propagating but not conveying. Therefore **none** of the [Section 4](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section4), [Section 5](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section5) and [Section 7](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section7) apply here. In this context, the AGPLv3 is not different from the GPLv3. This is like running an unmodified GPLv3 program that you call from your own code on a publicly accessible web server backend. The **copyleft is NOT triggered** in the sense you do not have to make any source code redistribution of your own code or of this library.

> **3. when I redistribute this application as a packaged software product to possible customers?**

You are using the library unmodified and there is still no built-in [Section 13](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section13) corresponding download mechanism (but that mechanism would not matter much in this case).

Here you are propagating AND conveying. Therefore the [Section 4](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section1) applies. In this context, the AGPLv3 is still not much different from the GPLv3. You are redistributing an application that is based on the unmodified AGPLv3-licensed library.

And the **copyleft is triggered**: you have to make a redistribution of the corresponding source code of both your own code and this library. In this case, this could also cover Tomcat, though Tomcat may also be treated as a "System Libraries" per [Section 1](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section1).

> **4. What if in my case 2. the author of the library insist that the copyleft is triggered even if I am using the library unmodified and that I must redistribute the whole source code, including my own?**

In this special case you **should never ignore this interpretation** (even though it looks clearly incorrect based on the facts I presented here) and you have two options:

1. You could consider that short of proper `Additional Terms` compliant with the [Section 7](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section7) of the AGPL, the author is trying to make a modification to the AGPL which is not OK under this license as the first statement says `Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies of this license document, but changing it is not allowed.`. You could discuss this with the author and if you want to take the high road involve the FSF in a private discussion at first to resolve the matter.
2. Or you could take this author assertions and comments at face value and treat this as if it were part of the license. This is usually my approach. E.g in this case and if you do not want to redistribute your source code when using the library unmodified in your case 2. you could just pass using this library entirely if anything because of its possibly incorrect and unclear licensing. Or use it and adopt its author's interpretation of the AGPLv3 -- even if not based on license text facts.

---

Finally let me provide some additional quotes supporting this answer:

- From Jeffrey Kaufman in his article [Do I need to provide access to source code under the AGPLv3 license?](https://opensource.com/article/17/1/providing-corresponding-source-agplv3-license):

  > What is often misunderstood is that the source code requirement in AGPLv3 Section 13 is triggered only where the AGPLv3 software has been modified by "you" (for example, the entity providing the network service). My interpretation is that, so long as "you" do not modify the AGPLv3 code, the license should not be read as requiring access to the Corresponding Source in the manner prescribed by Section 13. As I see it, many unmodified and standard deployments of software modules under AGPL simply do not trigger Section 13, although making the source code available even if not required under the license is a good idea.
- From @apsillers who relates his exchange with the Free Software Foundation in his answer to a very similar question: [Do I have to offer the source of an AGPL (v3.0) licensed Web app even if I didn’t modify it?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/791/947)

  > I wrote to the FSF's licensing team about this question:
  >
  > > [...] Does this [section 13] mean that if I run a *completely unmodified* AGPL-licensed program as a network service, I am *not* required to offer the source code to network users?
  >
  > And I received this response (bracketed phrase added by me):
  >
  > > [...] If you haven't modified the software then you are not required to add that functionality [i.e., to download the source]. Of course, if the functionality to download the source is already in the unmodified software, it will already be there for everyone to enjoy.
- This exchange with the FSF is consistent with the Free Software Foundation article on [Why the Affero GPL?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-affero-gpl.html):

  > [...]Suppose you develop and release a free program under the ordinary GNU GPL. If developer D modifies the program and releases it, the GPL requires him to distribute his version under the GPL too. Thus, if you get a copy of his version, you are free to incorporate some or all of his changes into your own version.
  >
  > But suppose the program is mainly useful on servers. When D modifies the program, he might very likely run it on his own server and never release copies. Then you would never get a copy of the source code of his version, so you would never have the chance to include his changes in your version. [...]

  and (with my additions in brackets):

  > If D runs his version **[e.g. the version that he modified]**  on a server that everyone can use, you too can use it. Assuming he has followed the license requirement to let the server's users download the source code of his version, you can do so, and then you can incorporate his changes into your version. (If he hasn't followed it, you have your lawyer complain to him.)
- Heather Meeker makes this consistent comment in her the book ["Open Source for Business"](https://i2.wp.com/ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BbdUrr5TL._SX331_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg) on page 134 after quoting the AGPL [section 13](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#section13):

  > Note that these requirements only exist if you modify the software. Mere users need not make the source code available. [...]
- And she further makes related comments in her article [AGPL: Out of the Shadows](http://blog.blackducksoftware.com/agpl-out-of-the-shadows):

  > [...]Not surprisingly, AGPL3 has been slower to propagate than GPL3; if GPL3 has gained acceptance slowly, AGPL3 has been tagging along behind like a younger sibling. But the license is not as scary as it seems. The network interaction provision only triggers source code offer requirements when you modify the Program. In fact, most open source software is used without modification from community versions.[...]
- And yet another comment in her article [The Gift that Keeps on Giving – Distribution and Copyleft in Open Source Software Licenses](http://www.ifosslr.org/ifosslr/article/view/66/125) that highlights what "convyeing" means:

  > A Clear Case in the Clouds 
  >   [...]
  >   Ultimately, this variation was removed from GPLv3 and memorialized in an alternative form of the license known as the “Affero GPL.” The basic form of GPLv3 makes clear that ASP or SAAS use does not trigger copyleft requirements. In GPLv3, copyleft is triggering by “conveying” rather than distribution, and “To ‘convey’ a work means any kind of propagation that enables other parties to make or receive copies. Mere interaction with a user through a computer network, with no transfer of a copy, is not conveying.”
  >   Under US law, distribution requires actual transfer of a copy, in whatever form. Therefore, under US law, SAAS use – which involves the access of software without transfer of a local copy to the user – does not trigger copyleft requirements.
- Dr. Miriam Ballhausen in the article [OpenSaaS: Using Free and Open Source Software as Software-as-a-Service](http://www.ifosslr.org/ifosslr/article/view/103/191#a__AGPL-3_0) makes this comment, with a point view of Germany (emphasis is mine):

  > According to Section 13 AGPL-3.0 the SaaS provider - as the person who offers his users to remotely interact with a program via a computer network - **is obliged to license any modifications to software licensed under AGPL-3.0 also under AGPL-3.0**. In particular, he must give all users (but not all third parties) the opportunity to obtain the corresponding source code of the software version made available via SaaS.

Comment: @apsillers I hope you do not mind if I quoted your exchange with the FSF

Comment: You are interpreting an interpretation of an IP lawyer who works for a billion dollar company as if it were a fact. That's similar to denying climate change based on research by a single scientist paid for by OPEC. A judge might not agree with the difference between "conveying" and "propagating." Also: it goes against the spirit of free software that free software licensed under the AGPL could suddenly become part of non-free software.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I do not think it is fair to summarize my answer as "interpreting an interpretation of an IP lawyer". I presented facts from the AGPL and I added quotes at the bottom that go in the same directions.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie about your comment on the "spirit": I think the AGPL preamble and other FSF articles and commentaries (that I referenced in my answer) are what best represents this spirit. This preamble clearly spells out the case of modified vs. unmodified use as the main "spiritual" point of the copyleft impact of the AGPL.

Comment: I'm still confused on how "using", "propagating" and "conveying" apply in this case. As I read it, the software in question is a library, not a stand-alone executable. So where do the different kinds of linking come into play? Why is the OP's software that depends on the (unmodified) AGPL library not considered derivative?

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer only point 2 because this is the core of the question. Basically the question is: **if I am building a public facing Java app on a private server and this app uses an AGPL library *unmodified*, am I impacted by section 13 of the AGPL license?**

This section starts with "if you modify the Program" so it boils down to deciding whether use of a Java library inside a Java app counts as modification of the library. Your interpretation is that this is not modification because the library itself was not modified. I think this is an incorrect interpretation which is caused by the use of the term "modify" while section 5 of (A)GPL talks about "a work based on the Program". However these two must be interpreted exactly in the same way because they are defined in the same paragraph of section 0:

> To "modify" a work means to copy from or adapt all or part of the work in a fashion requiring copyright permission, other than the making of an exact copy. The resulting work is called a "modified version" of the earlier work or a work "based on" the earlier work.

Consequently, the usual consideration about what it means for a work to be based on another work applies and you very well know that the FSF's interpretation of this includes linking to a library.

I'll conclude by saying that Google probably agree with this answer because they have [a special page dedicated to AGPL](https://opensource.google.com/docs/using/agpl-policy/) where we can read:

> Using AGPL software requires that anything it links to must also be licensed under the AGPL.

Comment: I feel that you may be conflating calling/using and modifying. How one could sustain a position that I am modifying a pre-built Java Jar fetched from Maven central when what I use is bit-for-bit identical to the one released by the project and I am just calling its code? I agree that the copyleft would flow to the caller... but I cannot fathom how one could argue that I modified anything. Aside from that the Google page is a nice find,  but Google policy and interpretation is just theirs.

Comment: I too find the terminology confusing but what I argue in my answer is that what the FSF is calling "modifying" is to be understood as synonymous of "making a derivative work" and you will agree that indeed calling an unmodified library is still making a derivative work (thus copyleft is triggered).

Comment: In any case, because section 0 of the license defines "to modify", you can't just use normal English understanding to interpret this word.

Comment: @Zimm Indeed, given the explicit definition, `"to modify"` is not just some English word any more. But obviously you need to obey the definition. And the definition includes the clause `"other than the making of an exact copy"`. So exact copying is not modifying and hence the resulting overall work is then not `"based on"` the original work and hence copyleft is not triggered.

Comment: @Lutz Prechelt: OP isn't making an exact copy – they've added their own code in order to produce the software that's running on their server.

To "modify" software doesn't just mean removing or replacing code. It can also mean adding code. So yes, all the bits they received from the library author are still there, but there are now also a lot of new bits that weren't there before.

That these additions happened in a different jar does not matter according to my understanding of the GPL or AGPL. Only the LGPL would allow us to treat the library as its own separate thing.

Comment: @Tordanik I don't think so. From the point of view of the original developer, all the new developer has done is `"making an exact copy"`. The new code is obviously under the copyright of the new developer, not the original developer, and so is not what the license is talking about. (As far as I understand, the GPL/LGPL difference was relevant for license version 2, but has more or less disappeared for license version 3.)

Answer (score 3):

I think your answer isn't complete. I will try to explain why using simple language (no legalese) and a specific example.

Let's say that you are using the AGPL library iText to create PDF documents. iText is a library that allows people to create PDF documents (in general) and you are using the iText jar to create PDF invoices (a very specific use case). By doing so, you have created a derived work. If you take away iText, your code doesn't make sense anymore: it no longer creates invoices. If you replace iText with something else (e.g. PdfBox), it doesn't work anymore either.

*Do you need to disclose your own source code?*

It depends.

**CASE 1:**

Suppose that you are using your application in batch. Every day, you create all the invoices of the previous day, and you store them on a server. People who want to see their invoice can go online and get their invoice from that server.

In that case, you can use iText without the AGPL kicking in, because you are using the library in a completely isolated way: you are not distributing it at all, so there is no source code to distribute either.

**CASE 2:**

You don't create the invoices in batch, but you create them *on-the-fly*: e.g. whenever a user buys something, he triggers a process that creates a PDF. That process involves iText code to be executed. If iText were GPL, you wouldn't have to distribute your code, because you are not distributing a copy, but since iText is AGPL, copyleft applies:

> Copyleft gives every person who receives a copy of a work permission to reproduce, adapt or distribute the work as long as any resulting copies or adaptations are also bound by the same copyleft licensing scheme.

Your derived work (e.g. creating PDF invoices) is an adaptation of iText (creating PDFs) and your work is bound by the same copyleft license.

**Summarized:**

In court, a judge will look at the involvement of the user.

- If the user doesn't trigger the copyrighted software in any way, you don't have to disclose the source code of your work.
- If the user triggers the execution of the copyrighted software, the license applies. In case of the AGPL, you have to disclose your source code to the user.

This is not my opinion, this is how it has been taught to me by different lawyers such as ([Crealaw](http://www.crealaw.eu/), [Stibbe](https://www.stibbe.com/), [Portelio](http://portelio.be/en/)).

See for instance the following slides by CreaLaw:

Software is covered by copyright law. The GPLv3 grants rights to users if they meet specific conditions:

[image]

Merely running GPLv3 software doesn't "activate" the conditions:

[image]

However: integrating GPLv3 software into an application, distributing,... can only be done if the GPLv3 is accepted.

[image]

In other words: the copyleft kicks in, and the AGPL makes the copyleft kick in even if the application runs on a network:

[image]

In this case, you must distribute your application under the (A)GPLv3:

[image]

This is inherent to the concept of copyleft.

Suppose that what I wrote wasn't true, then it would be possible for AGPL software to become part of closed source software. That goes against the spirit of the FSF.

Comment: Which references in the AGPL text do support your take?

Comment: Note that I added a new sub-question 4. and also answered it in my answer.

Comment: Note that my question is not specific to iText and the licensing riders that you use in https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/243c0531e389031359edb786b0ce66d8380761c6/LICENSE.md . There are two specifics there: 1. you have additional terms per th AGPL Section 7  and 2. you clearly spell out that you interpret that unmodified use triggers copyleft (and even if I disagree) this is something that I addressed in my subquestion 4. and its answer too, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne I have created a new Q&A explaining how one could rmake the AGPL act as if it were LGPL *if* you were right (but you aren't): http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/can-i-use-the-middleman-loophole-to-reduce-agpl-to-lgpl/5011 *If* you were right, there would be a serious loophole in the AGPL (but there isn't).

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne I have written this in other places, but your question "Which references in the AGPL text do support your take?" is irrelevant, because the AGPL is based on copyright law. See the definition of "modify": To "modify" a work means to copy from or **adapt all or part of the work in a fashion requiring copyright permission**, other than the making of an exact copy. Are you saying that you aren't using anyone's copyright when you integrate an AGPL library as a core piece of your own work?

Comment: Your point seems to hinge on the fact that you consider reusing a software package that is bit-for-bit identical to the one redistributed upstream means modifying it or adapting it in all cases, correct?  

I do not see anything in your references that would support this assertion.

And FWIW the terms of the AGPL seem rather material when we discuss AGPL, isn't it?

Comment: Compare it with the difference between the MIT license and the three-clause BSD license. The three-clause BSD license adds an extra clause about compiled source code that is actually redundant because the Berne convention in 1977 contains a part which expands the protection of the original work to translations too, which accords with the compilation of source code. In this case; I refer to copyright law. Copyright law can't be included in the AGPL because (1.) the AGPL would become bloated; and (2.) copyright law is different in different countries.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne How come my *reductio ad absurdum* couldn't convince you that your assumption was counter-intuitive? If what you claim were true, the middleman loophole would make the AGPL useless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52311/discussion-between-philippe-ombredanne-and-bruno-lowagie).

Comment: It was great to meet face to face at DEVOXX and discuss licensing! Now for the posterity there is one point that was missing in this thread: the licensing of iText has special provisions under section 7 of the AGPL. Which means that we are eventually both correct and best buddies!

Comment: Do you mind making some (even minor) edit to your answer so that I can upvote it again?

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne Feel free to edit. However, I don't think the special provision is necessary. We added it to make it 100% clear how the AGPL should be interpreted. It's a pity that lawyers shifted the interpretation of the AGPL, although I realize this is also caused by differences in international law. See http://ifosslawbook.org/ and please understand that iText interprets the AGPL under Belgian law.

Comment: I wish this answer actually addressed bullet #1 in the question. When all users in a company's internal network have access to the full source code of the non-public, internal-only application, then the terms of the AGPL are met, correct? Since there is no "public" access to the internal network, no public source distribution clause should be triggered.